# C++ : how to duplicate std::string *

Tags: c++, string

How can I, in c++, duplicate a std::string * ?

I want to do something like that :

```
std::string *str1 = new std::string("test");
std::string *str2 = strdup(str1);

delete str1;

std::cout << *str2 << std::endl; // result = "test"
```

Comment: An `std::string` is not *really* a char array on the stack, it only keeps some state information and has a pointer to a char array on the heap, where the actual contents of the string is stored. There are some optimizations in place which complicates the story, but this is essentially what an `std::string` does for you. It abstracts away the raw char array. So don't use pointers to `std::string`s, but rather use references in your functions like `std::string&`, or even better use `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you really must use pointers and dynamic allocation (most likely not), then

```
std::string *str2 = new std::string(*str1);
```

In real life,

```
std::string str1 = "test";
std::string str2 = str1;
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that you should not be using pointers here. Using pointers forces you to manage the lifetime, protect against exceptions and so on. A world of needless pain.

The code you ought to write is:

```
std::string str1 = "test";
std::string str2 = str1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just do

```
std::string *str2 = new std::string(*str1);
```

But I have to ask why you're using pointers in the first place. What's wrong with

```
std::string str1 = "test";
std::string str2 = str1;
```

?

Comment: I'm learning c++ and It's an exercise. I have a `std::string *` in a `class` and I have to Initialize It in an "copy constructor" function. I think that to do this, I need to duplicate my string instead of doing `my_var(this->var)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do more simpler without calling new and delete. For example

```
std::string *str1 = new std::string("test");
std::string *str2 = str1;

std::cout << *str2 << std::endl; // result = "test"
```

At least in your example if there is a possibility to access str1 after its deletion it would be better to write

```
std::string *str1 = new std::string("test");
std::string *str2 = new std::string( *str1 );

delete str1;
str1 = nullptr;

std::cout << *str2 << std::endl; // result = "test"
```

Comment: _"without calling new and delete"_ : both example still use the heap.

Comment: @Component  I was saying about new and delete not about the fact that class std::string uses memory in the heap.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You say the OP could do simpler without calling `new` and `delete` (I agree), but then your first example uses `new` and second uses `new` and `delete`

Comment: I am not too curious why he uses pointers in thsi abstract example. He did not ask what is better to use pointers or not. His question is different: how to simulate function strdup for pointers to std::string.